# Different Values Between API and Web Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am trying to automate the extraction of information from google analytics. I compare the result of the api and the web they are different. Although I'm applying the same filters in the web panel and the api.
I think the filters are correct because I get the same campaigns as a result, but with different values.

If someone can help me or explain the problem, I would appreciate it.

[Result Query Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43BUu.png)

[Result analytic dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVchL.png)

Comment: I have this exact issue right now